# knitr: wrapping computer output in HTML tags

Tags: r, html, knitr

With knitr, I'm trying to get the output wrapped in a div of a particular class. For example, here's the code:

`````
```{r}
# Print the pressure data set
head(pressure)
````
`````

I want the output (but not the code) to be wrapped in a div, like `<div class='myclass'>`, because the class provides special control over the output. (In my case, it will display in 2 columns)

I found this other question on StackOverflow, but the answer provided wraps the code and output in the div, whereas I just want the output to go in the div.

Can this be done with knitr?

EDIT:

Here's what's currently generated:

```
<pre class="r"><code>head(pressure)</code></pre>
<pre><code>##   temperature pressure
## 1           0   0.0002
## 2          20   0.0012
## 3          40   0.0060
## 4          60   0.0300
## 5          80   0.0900
## 6         100   0.2700</code></pre>
```

I would like something like this:

```
<pre class="r"><code>head(pressure)</code></pre>
<div class="myclass">
<pre><code>##   temperature pressure
## 1           0   0.0002
## 2          20   0.0012
## 3          40   0.0060
## 4          60   0.0300
## 5          80   0.0900
## 6         100   0.2700</code></pre>
</div>
```

But I would like it to be customizable for particular chunks. That is, I'd like to be able to set chunk options so that some chunks have output with `myclass` and others have output with `otherclass`.

Comment: On page http://goo.gl/Og7Xhj in the section Output Hooks there is a difference between 'source' and 'output'. Maybe this helps. Currently I can't test it here.

Comment: For clarity, please can you show the HTML that is generated, and the HTML that you'd like to see.

Comment: You refer to "this other question on StackOverflow" but not a link. This was awhile ago but any chance you can edit with the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a kind of minimal example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results='asis'}
knit_hooks$set(
  output = function(x, options) {
    # any decoration here
    paste0("<div class='myout'>", x, "</div><br/>")
    }
  )

```

<style>
.myout {background:red}
</style>

```{r}
mean(1:3)
sd(1:3)
var(1:3)
```
````

---

*UPDATE*

maybe this helps.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results='asis'}
ho0 <- knit_hooks$get('output')

knit_hooks$set(
  output = function(x, options) {
    if (is.null(options$class)) ho0(x)
    else 
      # any decoration here
      paste0("<div class='", options$class, "'>", ho0(x), "</div><br/>")
    }
  )

```

<style>
.myout {background:red}
.myout2 {background:skyblue}
</style>

```{r}
mean(1:3)
```
```{r class="myout"}
sd(1:3)
```
```{r class="myout2"}
var(1:3)
```
````

Note that you can define the hook outside the .Rmd.
Call `knit_hook$set` before `knit`.

Comment: thanks! But is it possible to customize it so that it looks more like the `output` method from `render_markdown`? Looking at `render_markdown`, the `output` method calls `hook.t`. I'd prefer if the .md output to be as close to normal as possible. I guess I could copy those other functions over from `render_markdown`, but the less code I have to put in the Rmd document, the better.

Comment: first, `render_markdown` defines functions to generate `md`, not `html`. You can define your original `render_hoge()` functions, so it is very easy to customize the output. But if you want something like `<div class="orz">` in the final html, you need to write html tag directly in .md or .Rmd. This is the limitation of markdown.

Comment: the updated version is helpful, but ideally it would also format the output using the functions from inside `render_markdown`, which add the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags, add `##`, and handle indentation, etc. I realize it's possible to re-implement this all myself but I would prefer not to. Thanks though, this solution will work for my purposes now.