# Text Blocks in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, css, r, knitr, r-markdown

I really like how text blocks look like when used in a code chunk. I even like the border of the box that wraps the text shading. I'm struggling to wrap text correctly either using `cat('Some paragraph here', comment=NA)` or `Some paragraph here`. I noticed there's a lot of stackoverflow questions dealing with `\n` strategies or `width` options. I also found that the author does not recommend using `cat` but instead using `message` or formatting as a block. See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html)

**Here's an example of a paragraph that will not render properly.**

````
```{r comment=NA}
cat('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.')
```
````

I understand that what I'm asking might be something `knitr`and `rmarkdown` were not designed for. However, if there are implementations with css (which I'm not familiar with), how should one write those `style.css`?

In the example, it goes like

````
```{block, type=FOO}
Your long text here
```
````

And you will have to include a `style.css`

```
div.FOO {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

(Which my little knowledge tells me it's not for producing the code blocks I want.). You should include them in the YAML somehow.

I couldn't find examples of these style.css files that people use to format text in that way. **My question is How to do this?**

Comment: sounds similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820888/knitr-wrapping-computer-output-in-html-tags) so you would use class not type

Comment: Also, you rly need to specify things like "This is being targeted for PDF output".

Comment: @hrbrmstr this is not being targeted for PDF output but a method that works for both would be highly desired