# How can I get a copy button in my Rmarkdown html output to copy a table generated in R code to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown, kableextra

I am trying to add a button to an html file that I'm producing using RStudio and rmarkdown that copies a table produced with `kableExtra` to the clipboard.

As a demo, the following produces and displays a table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

#making a dataframe into a table with kable


df<-data.frame(Flavor=c("Raspberry","Lemonade","Raspberry","Lemonade"),
           Color=c("Blue","Pink","Red","Yellow"))


table_out<-df%>%
  kable("html",align = 'clc')%>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F,position="left",bootstrap_options = c("striped","bordered"))%>%
  add_header_above(c("Colorful Stuff"=2))

table_out
```

I found that this code, borrowed from an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42210996/9731173,
allows me to produce a button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("copy");

    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
        range.execCommand("Copy");
    }
}
```

```
<input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="selectElementContents( 
document.getElementById('table_out') );">
```

The issue with the above (so far as I can tell) is that I'm not referring to the table I produced with `kableExtra` correctly.  When I click the Copy button in my rendered html file, it doesn't copy `table_out` to the clipboard.

**How can I give my `kableExtra` table an Id and correctly refer to it so that the "Copy" button I made copies the table to the clipboard?**

Edit: Here's what the rendered file looks like.  I'm happy with the appearance, but hope to make the copy button functional:

[image]

Comment: maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820888/knitr-wrapping-computer-output-in-html-tags

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by adding the id attribute to my `kableExtra` table, and then referencing the id in the copy button.

Looking at 10.1.11 here:https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html ,
you can use `table.attr` to add attributes.

You'll see that I changed the `kableExtra` part to include `table.attr = "id=mytab"`, which allows for reference outside the chunk of R code

My functioning code in it's entirety is:

````
---
title: "Demo"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```



```{r}
#making a dataframe into a table with kable


df<-data.frame(Flavor=c("Raspberry","Lemonade","Rasp2berry","Lemonade"),
           Color=c("Blue","Pink","Red","Yellow"))


table_out<-df%>%
  kable("html",align = 'clc', table.attr = "id=mytab")%>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F,position="left",bootstrap_options = 
c("striped","bordered"))%>%
  add_header_above(c("Colorful Stuff"=2))

table_out

```





<script type="text/javascript">
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("copy");

    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
        range.execCommand("Copy");
    }
}
````

```
<input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('mytab') );">
```

If you have a better solution, or stronger explanation, please still consider posting an answer.  My solution is the result of brute force, not a wealth of knowledge.